# Openwhisk Docker different behavior from IBM cloud CLI than its frontend

Tags: python, docker, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I want to run my Python program on IBM cloud functions, because of dependencies this needs to be done in an OpenWhisk Docker. I've changed my code so that it accepts a json:

```py
json_input = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
INSTANCE_NAME = json_input['INSTANCE_NAME']
```

I can run it from the terminal:

`python main/main.py '{"INSTANCE_NAME": "example"}'`

I've added this Python program to OpenWhisk with this Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile for example whisk docker action
FROM openwhisk/dockerskeleton

ENV FLASK_PROXY_PORT 8080

### Add source file(s)
ADD requirements.txt /action/requirements.txt
RUN cd /action; pip install -r requirements.txt

# Move the file to 
ADD ./main /action
# Rename our executable Python action
ADD /main/main.py /action/exec

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cd actionProxy && python -u actionproxy.py"]
```

But now if I run it using IBM Cloud CLI I just get my Json back:

```
ibmcloud fn action invoke --result e2t-whisk --param-file ../env_var.json
# {"INSTANCE_NAME": "example"}
```

And if I run from the IBM Cloud Functions website with the same Json feed I get an error like it's not even there.

```sh
stderr: INSTANCE_NAME = json_input['INSTANCE_NAME']",
stderr: KeyError: 'INSTANCE_NAME'"
```

What can be wrong that the code runs when directly invoked, but not from the OpenWhisk container?

Comment: Did you try logging the input arguments to see what’s being passed in?

Comment: Like this? 
`json_input = json.loads(sys.argv[1])`
`print json_input`
I have. It didn't print anything. I don't invoke it in the `__main__.py` but in the file where I actually need the env variables. Could that be the problem?